# how to hide play button until image loaded in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to hide play button image until video thumbnail is loaded.

```js
<img
  src={
    //video thumbnail image is coming from api results.
    media &&
    getShapedImage(
      media[0].thumb ? media[0].thumb.url : media[0].url,
      imageSize.large,
      null,
      fileFormat.jpgFormat
    )
  }
  alt="single image"
  className="single-image-width"
/>
{
  media[0].thumb && (
    <div className="play-btn">
      <img src={PlayBtnImage} className="mobile-width" /> //video play button
      image is here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman why did you delete your answer?

Comment: actully I am new for stackoverflow i  am checking settings by mistakenly those are gone,not deleted intentionally.

Comment: Hi  Praveen Kumar Garu,If you time please look at this once please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919122/how-to-get-proper-pdf-from-react-js-piece-of-code-using-html2pdf-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`onLoad`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#image-events) event of image and use states to manage the display of the button.

```js
<img
  src={
    //video thumbnail image is coming from api results.
    media &&
    getShapedImage(
      media[0].thumb ? media[0].thumb.url : media[0].url,
      imageSize.large,
      null,
      fileFormat.jpgFormat
    )
  }
  // Add this here.
  onLoad={e => {
    if (e.target.complete) {
      this.setState({
        imgLoaded: true
      });
    }
  }}
  alt="single image"
  className="single-image-width"
/>;
{
  // Update here.
  media[0].thumb && this.state.imgLoaded && (
    <div className="play-btn">
      <img src={PlayBtnImage} className="mobile-width" /> //video play button
      image is here
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not that it matters much, but `onload` is lowercase (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#handler-onload)

Comment: @evolutionxbox This is React JS...  Look at [Image Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#image-events)... Also updated the doc link in my answer... 

Comment: May you add that tag to the question? The OP hasn't included it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Good thought. Done! 